# Pan sharpen Landsat 8 using Grass 7

Tags: grass-gis, remote-sensing, landsat-8, pansharpening

I have followed [this great tutorial on pan sharpening](http://courses.neteler.org/processing-landsat-8-data-in-grass-gis-7-rgb-composites-and-pan-sharpening/) using Grass GIS 7 (I'm using beta 3). Everything in the tutorial seemed to have worked, but my final output is not as expected (pictured below).
[image: PanSharp RGB output]

I tried with various sharpening methods, colour balancing stages and with and without atmospheric correction. I also tried with different images.

Any advice on where I'm going wrong?

Here's the output from r.univar:

### Of the non-null cells:

n: 41623319
minimum: 0.089549
maximum: 1.17079
range: 1.08124
mean: 0.161591
mean of absolute values: 0.161591
standard deviation: 0.110987
variance: 0.0123181
variation coefficient: 68.6836 %
sum: 6725971.35730981

Comment: What are the pixel value stats? Please add the output of r.univar somechannel to your post.

Comment: Is it possible that a radiance versus reflectance mishap happened?

Comment: Radiance-reflectance mishap - I'm not sure. Would it Provide some insight if I ran i.toar in verbose mode?

Comment: Please, post full commands to make clear, for example, on which maps the statistics refer to. Also, for the sharpening part, you can give a try of this one: [i.fusion.hpf](https://github.com/NikosAlexandris/i.fusion.hpf) (works for GRASS GIS ver. 7.x).

Answer (score 3):

Thank you Nikos and Markus for the comments.

Using Nikos' hpf module I get a nice pansharpened image.
The steps taken to do this (also in [i.fusion.hpf documentation](https://github.com/NikosAlexandris/i.fusion.hpf)):

- Download the module from github, open Grass 7.x.x
- In the Grass command console (bottom of the layer manager window, second tab from the left), navigate to the directory where you extracted the github archive (eg: cd c:\somefolder\ifusion...). Then run 'make MODULE_TOPDIR=$GISBASE'
- Run the i.fusion.hpf module (eg. i.fusion.hpf -l -c --o pan=L_B8 msx=L_B2,L_B3,L_B4 center=high modulation=max). Refer to documentation for explanations and other options. For me, it took 21 mins
- Colour enhance (eg. i.colors.enhance red=L_B4.hpf@Morogoro green=L_B3.hpf@Morogoro blue=L_B2.hpf@Morogoro)
- display rgb or make a composite (eg. r.composite red=L_B4.hpf@Morogoro green=L_B3.hpf@Morogoro blue=L_B2.hpf@Morogoro output=MorogoroPanSharpen

(This was done on a Windows machine)

Here's the result from an image of part of Tanzania - before (left) and after (right):
[image: Pansharpened before and after]

The river and crops are sharper and you can make out clumps of trees on the barren patches.

Comment: The sharpening effect is obvious in the screenshots (more details on the right image). Yet, the colors are not vivid/contrast not high(?). Maybe the appearance can be improved further by experimenting with `i.colors.enhance`. What is the purpose of the sharpening in this case? Nice visuals or subsequent classification?